# SQL Case Order By specific order and Direction

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, case

I have a table that I need sorted on fields By @SortBy and @SortDirection,

for **ID,PriorityID,stateType (column type is int)**  result is OK, but for **Title (nvarchar)** Query Result is:

`Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Title Column value' to data type int.`

Query:

```
             CASE 
                WHEN @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN
                 CASE @SortBy
                    WHEN 'ID' THEN ID --int
                    WHEN 'Title' THEN Title  --nvarchar
                    WHEN 'PriorityID' THEN [Priority] --int
                    WHEN 'stateType' THEN [state] --int
                    
                 end
              END ASC
              ,case WHEN @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN
                CASE @SortBy
                    WHEN 'ID' THEN ID 
                    WHEN 'Title' THEN Title 
                    WHEN 'Priority' THEN [Priority]
                    WHEN 'state' THEN [state]
                END
            END DESC
```

Comment: A case expression's different return values must have compatible data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The types are different, and that is a problem for the `case` expressions.  The simplest method is a different `case` for each possibility:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 'ASC' AND @SortBy = 'ID' THEN ID END) ASC,
         (CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 'ASC' AND @SortBy = 'Title' THEN Title END) ASC,
         . . .
```